# PHP : get the highest and lowest value among variables

Tags: php

Is their any way to get the highest and lowest value among variables?

example is that i have this variables

```
$val1 = 10
 $val2 = 20
 $val3 = 30
 $val4 = 40
 $val5 = 50
```

and among this variable i want to display or put to another variable the variable that has the highest and lowest value. just like below.

```
$highval = $val5; 
$lowval = $val1;
```

`$val5` in `$highval` coz it has the value of 50
and
`$val1` in `$lowval` coz it has the value of 10 .

thanks

Comment: Where is `$val51`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are comparing a list of values, it's the best to store them in an array.

Try this:

```
$val1 = 10;
$val2 = 20;
$val3 = 30;
$val4 = 40;
$val5 = 50;

$arr = compact('val1','val2','val3','val4','val5');  // Stores values in array $arr
$highval = max($arr); // 50
$lowval  = min($arr);  // 10
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to put the scores in an array, like so:

```
$scores = array(1, 2, 4, 5);
$highest = max($scores);
$lowest = min($scores);
```

Comment: sorry dude.i will not be using array coz the variables is fetch by different queries on my database

Comment: You know that the selected answer uses array too, right?

Comment: now i get your point. .but i just up voted it coz the other answer is much more clearer for me. and that's the reason i understand your answer. and btw thanks for answering

Comment: @ooo-Ghost-ooo Okay, well glad to help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

well maybe you already find the solution ...

variables must not include numbers like your example

```php
$val1 = 10;
$val2 = 20;
$val3 = 30;
$val4 = 40;
$val5 = 50;

$arr = compact('val1 ', 'val2 ', 'val3 ', 'val4 ', 'val5 ');
$highval = max($arr);
$lowval = min($arr);
```

```php
echo "$lowval"; //  give val1 the first variable value In brackets inside
echo "$highval"; // give val5 the last variable value In brackets inside
```

```html
lowval  is val1 (10)
highval is val5 (50)
The above example will give correct results 
(you got the right results because it happened 
to have the values ​​in ascending order).
WHY IS THIS WRONG !!! 
see below
```

PLEASE NOTE
If the data comes from a database or an xml file then the values ​​are dynamic and not ascending, in this case we will get back the wrong results.

```
$val1 = 20;
$val2 = 30;
$val3 = 10;
$val4 = 50;
$val5 = 40;

$arr = compact('val1 ', 'val2 ', 'val3 ', 'val4 ', 'val5 ');
$highval = max($arr);
$lowval = min($arr);
```

```
 echo"$lowval"; // val1 give the first variable value In brackets inside
 echo"$highval"; // val5 give the last variable value In brackets inside
```

```html
The above example will give wrong results 
lowval is val1 (20)
highval isval5 (40)
The right results are
lowval=val3 (10)
highval=val4 (50)
```

A simple solution is to replace the numbers with letters

```
$val1 = 30;
$val2 = 10;
$val3 = 50;
$val4 = 40;
$val5 = 20;

$vala = "$val1";
$valb = "$val2";
$valc = "$val3";
$vald = "$val4";
$vale = "$val5";

$arr = compact('vala ', 'valb ', 'valc ', 'vald ', 'vale ');
$highval = max($arr);
$lowval = min($arr);
```

now the results is correct

```php
 echo "$lowval"; // give valb the lower value
 echo "$highval"; // give valc the higher value
```

```html
Now the results is correct 
lowval is valb (10)
highval is valc (50)
```